# Error converting .hyper tableau file to a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, tableau-api, hyper-api

I downloaded a datasource using Tableau rest api and it downloads it in a .tdsx format. 
Upon extracting it, I got the .hyper file I was looking for. Now I'm trying to load the .hyper file into a pandas dataframe using this:

```
import pantab
result = pantab.frames_from_hyper(database=<PATH TO YOUR HYPER FILE>)
```

But everytime this line executes, I get an error message saying python has stopped responding, close the program. I am assuming that this is because the file contents are too large to load which is causing it to crash. The .hyper size is 44.3 MB. Any work arounds or suggestions to solve this?

Comment: This doesn't sound good. 44MB shouldn't be too big. Maybe a crash in Hyper?

Comment: Just to exclude any weirdness: could you create a fresh virtual environment, install the newest `pantab` version there, and try again? 44MB is definitely not too big.

Comment: In the past, there were some crashes due to version mismatches between `pantab` and the underlying version of `tableauhyperapi`.
I would recommend to try a few different versions of tableauhyperapi (see https://pypi.org/project/tableauhyperapi/#history for the available versions) and hope that one of those versions works for you

Comment: How did you extract the .tdsx file in Python?